PowerBI - Extracting hours from datetime
I've tried every example I can find but cannot get this to work as expected. I've played with Rounddown, Time, and filtering the cells.
I believe I need a Dax formula for a new column that reduces this to just hours if anyone can assist.

It does not matter if the format is 3PM or 15 for example, I just need to be able to filter by hours on my chart.

You could try converting the DATETIME into TIME data type with something like this : TimeOnly = FORMAT([YourDateTimeColumn], "hh:mm:ss")  Now keep in mind if the time rolls over to the next day, you are going to have to build all kinds of code to deal with that, as DATETIME and TIME only deal with 24/hours, so when you roll it over it doesnt go to a new day, but back to the start of the same day.

you can try to use hour function
Column = hour('Table'[Calls start time])


